# Working with facebook Like button and FSQL

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I have develop Facebook application and added page tab on my page.

I have read Facebook documentation for canvas application development and adding application on page tab.

I want to show different page for people who click on Like button on my page and different page to people who not click on like button.

After reading documentation I found that it is possible using FSQL but I am not getting any result from my sql queries

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/url_like/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

```
require_once 'facebook.php';

// *** Add your Facebook API Key, Secret Key here ***
$appapikey = '*********';
$appsecret = '**********';
$facebook = new Facebook($appapikey, $appsecret);
// $user_id = $facebook->require_login();


//$fql    =   "select name from user where uid=me()";
//$fql    =   "SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id='122706168308'";
$fql    =   "SELECT user_id, object_id, post_id FROM like WHERE user_id=me()";

$param  =   array(
       'method'     => 'fql.query',
        'query'     => $fql,
      'callback'    => ''
);
$fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);

echo"hi";
echo"<pre>";
print_r($fqlResult);
echo"</pre>";
```

Any idea how to make it working?

- Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

did you authorized app at first ?

PS:  its not FSQL its fql i mean you are not able to use all sql commands in fql

Comment: I have no idea about how authorized app but when I run sql from following page it is working as expected and i am getting result https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/

Comment: Now I am getting empty array Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
        )

)

Comment: at first you must authorize application with needed permissions

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

Comment: Thanks pooya. After authentication it is working .I want to retrieve all users id who Like my page. I try following query but not getting result. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/

Comment: Thanks for Pooya. I got it working.I have not implemented any SSL certificate for my canvas applications and facebook pages therefore it creating problem with https link. could you please give information about .crt file implantation for my pages and applications

Comment: you want to add ssl to your website (of apps) ?
well, i did it in my vps ,not sure it be possible in shared hosts 
anyway all you need to do is purchasing an ssl certification & tell to your hosting support to install it

Comment: I want SSL for my facebook apps and I found facebook SDK example has facebook.php and base_facebook.php and fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt file in src folder .So if replace my .crt file in src folder for my domain will it work? also change name in base_facebook.php file  around line 886.

Comment: That crt file is for facebook & for data transfer between Facebook & your server ( not between user & your server) you need to purchasing a unique ssl certificate ( include .crt & .key & . . . files) just for your domain name 

if you dont buy an ssl certificate only users who are using facebook in normal ( not secure) mode will be able to see your app

Comment: Hi Pooya My Facebook application working as expected now I have dedicated web hosting + certificate of my registered domain how can I integrate .crt file with my Facebook applications using Facebook php sdk. Thanks

Comment: please write your app link at first please :)

Comment: Hi Pooya, I have not publish the apps until I complete development. I want to know how can I remove vertical scroll bar from my apps.facebook.com/appname page because my app running in iframe I am getting scroll bar. any idea?

Comment: well,thats easy go https://developers.facebook.com/apps
Select your app click on the Edit Settings click on Advanced Then
scroll down to Canvas Settings & choose Canvas Height:Fixed
then save settings

Comment: Hi,

I got ssl certificate from my domain.

I want to know how to integrate SSL certificate with my facebook application page.

My facebook application is simple. I have one html page in my facebook.

If I put SSL certificate in my directory and how to configure it to work.

- Thanks

Comment: Thanks Pooya for the information.My have develop facebook canvas application and it works in Iframe. I want to know how it will work on facebook page tab instead of going in outside page tab